# What is the correct way to pass a token to axios from React?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

The question sounds vague so allow me to explain. I am wondering, what is the correct/best way to pass get a `token` from `local storage` and pass it into my `axios` request.

This is what I am doing now, and I am sure this is not correct so I want to fix it but am unsure how.

I have a component called `TicketsComponent` that requires authorization. Therefore, in `componentDidMount()`, I validate the token, and if its invalid then send the user back to login, otherwise, load the tickets. It looks like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    // validate token
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    AuthService.validateToken()
      .then((res) => {
        if (res == undefined || res == null || !token) {
          this.props.history.push("/login");
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        TicketService.getTickets().then((res) => {
          if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({ tickets: res.data });
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

**Both** `AuthService.validateToken()` and `TicketService.getTickets()` require the JWT in the header. Here are those two functions:

```
  validateToken() {
    return axios
      .get(API_BASE_URL + "authenticate", {
        headers: {
          token: this.getTokenFromLocalStorage(),
        },
      })
      .then("did it")
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("failed to validate token" + error);
        return null;
      });
  }
```

```
  getTickets() {
    console.log("getting tickets!");
    console.log("Environment variable: " + process.env.NODE_ENV);
    return axios
      .get(API_BASE_URL + "tickets", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getTokenFromLocalStorage()}` },
      })
      .then("yessssss")
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("failed to get tickets" + error);
      });
  }
```

The problem is that both `AuthService` and `TicketService` share the same function called `getTokenFromLocalStorage()`. That looks like this:

```
  getTokenFromLocalStorage() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log("the token is -> " + token);
    if (token === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return token;
  }
  catch(err) {
    return undefined;
  }
```

So obviously this is not ideal. I have the same function in two services just to get the token from the header. What is the recommended way of doing this?

EDIT: I hope this kind of question is allowed. Even though the code is not actually broken per se, I still think this is useful to beginners like me to implement best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a shared [axios instance](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) like so:

```js
const API_BASE_URL = 'https://example.com/api/'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getTokenFromLocalStorage()}` },
});
```

Then you'd just import "instance" into the components and call:

```js
import {instance} from '../wherever' // decide if you want to import default or not 

// make sure to either include or exclude the / in the first parameter passed into the request method (e.g. '/authenticate' or 'authenticate') below based on whether you provided a / in the API_BASE_URL

instance.post('authenticate', {
  // any additional config relevant to the request, e.g:
  data: {
    username: 'my user!',
    password: 'super_secret_password'
  }
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you show how I would call it with different requests? For example a `post` vs `put` and what about different endings to the `baseUrl` as well?

Comment: I did add a link to the documentation which shows how to use the axios instance, but I'll edit the post now too

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I am not home/was on my phone, I will before to checkout the link and your answer in more detail. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, I've update the answer at any rate which should help but I'd still suggest checking out the documentation link I posted which will send you directly to the part about the 'instance', and the next page is the config (which is all the stuff you pass as the second parameter to the post or get methods) - if you are still stuck feel free to comment back :)